# Плавная прокрутка в scrollviewer в приложении wpf на планшете

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет. Есть приложение wpf со scrollviewer работающее на windows 10 , в котором есть n-ое количество TextBlock. Всё это дело работает на планшете с возможностью пролистывания по вертикали жестами пальцев. В самом scrollviewer выставил свойства PanningMode="Both" и PanningRate="n", но проблема в том, что пролистывание осуществляется рывками. Пытался изменять значение PanningRate, но результата нет.
А мне хотелось бы сделать как здесь: https://youtu.be/2WWn1h12PuQ?t=81, ну в общем как в Android. Помогите мне если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и решил её.

Comment: CanContentScroll или как-то так надо в false выставить, чтобы попиксельно скорлить, еще можно ScrollUnit вроде задать. Но я точно не помню, как там оно.

Comment: Спасибо, CanContentScroll="false" я вроде пробовал, но результата не было.